# Routing a post says missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm rather confused about this; I have a custom route here.

I have a groups/:id/new_caretaker. This has a form on it. Whenever that form is POSTed it should go to the same page; But to a different method.

However, if I post the form it says `Missing template groups/create_caretaker, application/create_caretaker`

How can I fix this?

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "groups", action: "create_caretaker", method: "post") do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag('email') %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Opslaan"%>
<% end %>
```

And my routes:

```
  get "/groups/:id/new_caretaker" => "groups#new_caretaker", :as => :new_caretaker
  post "/groups/:id/new_caretaker" => "groups#create_caretaker"
```

Added groups.controller methods:

Note: new_caretaker gets @group from a `:before_action`

```
  def new_caretaker

  end

  def create_caretaker
    email = params[:email]

    if !email.blank?
      userToAdd = User.find_by_email(email)
      if userToAdd.blank?
        #User doesn't exist
      else
        #User does exist
        respond_to do |format|
          if @group.users.find_by_id(userToAdd)
            @theAlert = 'Deze gebruiker zit al in de groep en is niet toegevoegd'
            format.html { render action: 'new_caretaker' }
            format.json { render json: @theAlert, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          else
            @group.users << userToAdd
            format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'De begeleider is toegevoegd.' }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Your problem is that the id is not being passed in your url

Comment: Yes it is: `http://localhost:3000/groups/1/new_caretaker?method=post`

Comment: Could you share you controller?

Comment: In its entirety or the methods involved?

Comment: I've added the methods involved; If you need more gimme a shout!

Comment: Looks like the controller is trying to render in this section ` if userToAdd.blank?
        #User doesn't exist
      else`  That's why it's looking for a 'create_caretaker' template

Comment: Aahh, How can I get around it? I do want to show an error on the new_caretaker form page(Such as Rails' own practice)

Comment: P.S escaping everything in `create_caretaker` still throws that error :')

Comment: Something along the lines of `format.html { render action: "new" }`

Comment: I'm so confused; This worked up to a point that I was satisfied. Leaving the page and coming 5 minutes later throws this nonsense on me. 2 empty methods still give me the template missing error. Is it something to do with my routes?

Comment: Oh, i Fixed it.... The render was in the else. There was no rendering in the IF at all(If the user didnt exist)

Answer (score 0):

The `if !email.blank?` => false and `if userToAdd.blank?` => true branches don't render or redirect. Therefor rails if looking for a template with the name of that action.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to enhance you routing editing `routes.rb`:

```
resources :groups do
  member do
    get 'new_caretaker'
    post 'create_caretaker'
  end
end
```

And then you call this redirect:

```
redirect_to group_new_caretaker_path(@group)
```

in the controller when needed.

This way, you'll also get a `params[:group_id]` param in the `new_caretaker` controller method to be able to handle group-related data (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

The fix: I did not render anything in the `if`, just in the `else`. Some good tips in the answers though.